# How to infer the graph of $x^2 - x$ from the graphs of $x^2$ and $x$?

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

I'm puzzled on this one.  I've studied James Stewart's graph translations, but I think his techniques don't obviously solve this one.  Or what am I missing?

**The problem**.  The problem (which is not from Stewart's book) shows a table of values of the functions $f(n) = n$, $g(n) = n^2$, $h(n) = \sqrt{n}$.  The problem then asks some easy questions such as --- which one grows more slowly? (Surely $h$.)  Which one has constant growth?  (Surely $f$.)  Then the problem asks me to build a table of values for a function $y$ that maps $n$ to $n^2 - n$.  It asks me to draw the graph.  I do it.  Then it asks me --- is it possible to draw the graph of $y$ by using just the graph of $n^2$ and $n$?  Honestly, I don't know.

The graph itself seems very simple.  It surely is still a curve that looks like a parabola, but I'm not even sure I can call it a parabola.  (To me the definition of a parabola is that curve whose any point on it is far away from its vertex as much as it is far away from the directrix.) **Anyway, how can I draw the graph of $x^2 - x$ from $x^2$ and $x$?**  (Is that even possible --- at least in this case?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, a spoiler:

$y = x^2 - x$ is indeed a parabola. We can write it as $y = (x - \frac{1}{2})^2 - \frac{1}{4}$, so it is just the parabola $y = x^2$ shifted right by $\frac{1}{2}$ and down by $\frac{1}{4}$.

As for how you can intuit its graph from the graphs of $y = x$ and $y = x^2$, you can pick out some of the following features:

1. The graphs intersect at $(0, 0)$ and $(1, 1)$, so $y = x^2 - x$ must have $x$-intercepts at $x = 0, 1$.
2. $y = x$ takes negative values to the left of $x = 0$ so $y = x^2 - x$ must be above the graph of $y = x^2$ on that side, and similarly it must be below the graph of $y = x^2$ to the right of $x = 0$.
3. As you noted, $y = x^2$ grows faster than $y = x$ when $x$ increases (and similarly it grows faster than $y = -x$ when $x$ decreases), so the curve of $y = x^2 - x$ will be dominated by the graph of $y = x^2$ for large (positive or negative) $x$.

You could probably also, with some effort, intuit something about it having a single minimum between $x = 0$ and $x = 1$, and it having reflection symmetry about $x = \frac{1}{2}$, but once you get familiar with the algebraic manipulation it will probably be much easier to do those things by converting the formula to another standard form.

Comment: You are very skilled!  Could you elaborate just a bit on what you mean by "converting the formular to another standard form"?  (Maybe give an example instead of elaborating?)

Comment: There are a few ways to write the equation of a parabola, and each of them gives different information about it. For example, as I wrote above you can have $y = a(x-h)^2 + k$, where $a$ is a scaling parameter and $(h, k)$ is the vertex. You can also have $y = a(x-b)(x-c)$, which tells you where the $x$-intercepts are, and there's also a parametric form $(x, y) = (h + 2at, k + at^2)$ which is more closely related to the focus and directrix.

Comment: I see what you mean now.  Thank you so much!